# Running network cable near X-Ray equipment

Tags: ethernet, interface, cables, shielding

My mother runs a small veterinary clinic. She is getting a new X-Ray machine that will need a network connection to send digital copies of the X-Ray to the server. I will be installing a wall plate with a few Ethernet jacks in the X-Ray room.

Do I need to do anything special like shielded cabling for this install? I am not worried about transmission errors that may occur during the split second the X-Ray is active, TCP can fix those, I am concerned about damaging the NIC card on the computer or router in the wiring closet due to some form of current induction.

The cable will not be running in the direct path of the X-Ray beam just be in wall leading to the room. Am I being overly cautious or is this a legitimate concern? Also if I need to route under the path of the beam for some reason are there any consequences for that?

Comment: Interesting question. I hope that someone will be able to give technical explanation. You may want to consider asking same thing at Super User too. Some people there might have practical experience with network cables and X-Ray equipment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything special. We have X-ray generators and Digital Imaging devices everywhere at my place of work, we run cable around them, in front of them sometimes(tie comes loose) and all around them. We have never had issues.

Other forms of radiation can have very negative affects on materials and electronics, but on ethernet cable we do not see negative affects from these either.

X-Rays are not that terrible, it is just not a good idea to get a dose from them repeatedly throughout the day. This is why the therapist is placed behind a bit of lead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, some of the higher end radiation we have stops the storage of computers in the room. It will cause complete failure.

Comment: @Kortuk - Scott's comment has gone missing; what was the context?

Comment: @reemrevnivek, It is very very hard to figure that out. I am not sure what happened. If it was offensive another mod may have removed it. More likely, he chose to remove it and deleted it himself.

Comment: I did not remove it, and I did not think I said anything offensive.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I am sorry to say only full devs can look into these things. People have told me that someone probably removed it and forgot. I know I did not, I do not remember even reading it. what was the comment?

Comment: @Kortuk, I don't remember what the the comment was either :)